# Two software applications, same model but different views and controllers

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, architecture

I'm searching for an elegant and practical way of sharing a model between 2 differents programs whithout compiling them separately.

I am developing 2 differents software for the same customer. Both share the same functionality in a different way (volume filling optimisation). But the user interface is both heavy and different therefore i wish to split them in 2 different software for clarity.

But in order to reuse code and make it easily maintainable i wish for an architechture like a core and two separated/specialized layer for each soft.

I thought about creating a .dll or .so that both apps would share it but i am develloping on linux and the customer is using windows, so i find it quite heavy to port the application this way. (I don't own any computer running windows so I'm going for a late port)

I also thought about creating a command line program as the core and calling it through the shell while running the softs, but this seems impossible to do in a portable way.

Is there a simple and portable way of doing this (much like importing modules in python) i didn't find about in C++?
or if not, would it be best to use a shared library or compile both softs with the core included?

Comment: " i am develloping on linux and the customer is using windows, so i find it quite heavy to port the application this way. (I don't own any computer running windows so i'm going for a late port) " <- To me, that doesn't sound like a good idea *at all*.

Comment: I don't have regular accesss to a windows environment and cross-compiling really doesn't excite me much...

Comment: What is stopping you from getting a Windows license? Anyways, which cross-platform UI toolkit are you using?

Comment: i use wxWidget for gui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"compile both softs with the core included" - Is preferred for the sake of convenience from the point of view of a developer.

If you really want to use a piece of compiled crossplatform code you'll probable have to write  a c-style dll.